# OLAP-Pentaho and m2m relations

Tags: pentaho, olap, workbench, m2m

Could sb tell me, does the implementation of Pentaho OLAP support connections m2m (many -to-many)?
Need to solve a task:
The data stored in the following tables :

```
1.  Table facts: facts (fact_id, loc_id, ...)
2 . Table persons : persons (person_id, name)
3 . Table relation between persons and facts : con_facts_pesons (id, fact_id, person_id)
4 . Table locations: locations (loc_id, name)
```

The OLAP cube (the fact table ) contains two dimensions: persons and  locations
And one Measure: count (fact_id).

I need to build a query like this:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures]. [Count]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize ({[Location]. [Location]. Members})} ON ROWS
FROM [Docs]
WHERE {[Persons]. [Jay], [Persons]. [Tom]}
```

as a result should get a data like this:

```
Location_name    Count of facts 
Location_1     ---            2 
Location_2     ---            4 
Location_3     ---            5 
Location_4     ---            2
```

Locations that are associated with the facts that have a connection with persons of Tom and Jay.

Comment: I've attempted this with s bridge table as per kimball in the past.  Mondrian half worked but I don't think I had it quite right as I got things counted twice.  We did get right values using distinct counts but that wss really a hack not a viable solution